# Using EXCEL as datasource through Microsoft OLE DB provider

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, oledb, recordset

We are frequently using some Excel files as a datasource for massive imports in our database. At the code level, we always refer to the corresponding data source as:

```
set rs = New ADODB.recordset
rs.open "SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", myConnectionString, etc
```

Of course, this procedure only works when there's a sheet in the Excel file which is named [sheet1]. I'd like to add some sheet management code here, but without having to create an instance of the original Excel file, opening it, and so on (my users might get a file with a different sheet name, and might not have Excel installed).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a recordset with the ADO OpenSchema method and then list the table (sheet) names in your workbook.

```
Public Sub SheetsInWorkbook()
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "temp.xls"
    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
        & "Data Source='" & strPath & "';" _
        & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0';"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.ConnectionString = strConnect
    cn.Open
    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(20) '20 = adSchemaTables '
    Debug.Print "TABLE_NAME"
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print rs!TABLE_NAME
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thumbs up for HansUp! Thanks!

Comment: I expect this is more efficient than automating Excel to open the spreadsheet and checking the name of the first worksheet in the workbook, which is how I've always done it.